# Is my platy fish pregnant?

Tags: fish

Hoping someone can help advise me. Is my platy pregnant? Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets. It's hard to tell from the photo, but if this fish is pregnant then her pregnancy isn't advanced, it's at most at its beginning stage. I am telling so because this platy's abdomen isn't looking "boxy" and I can't see the gravid spot (dark spot made by eggs inside the fish).

Comment: I am sorry but according to the site rules I had to close this as a duplicate of existing question. Please take a look at this existing question. If at any point of her life past her larva stage this fish has been in a tank with a male platy then she is almost surely pregnant. But her colouring makes it hard to tell until it's at least medium-advanced because she is opaque in the middle.